# Как извлечь название файла из свойства средствами Python

Tags: python, mp3

Необходимо извлечь из свойства файла в блоке описание, само название файла. См. скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: «название файла» (обычно употребляют термин «имя файла») нарисовано вами в верхней части рисунка. что-то вроде `iMabpvmvj8roYAUx.mp3`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+mp3+теги

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948/accessing-mp3-metadata-with-python здесь решение

Comment: Классно, спасибо за помощь, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти данные хранятся в ID3-тэгах MP3 файла.
В свое время я давал ответ на подобный вопрос (только тогда надо было извлечь изображения из тэгов).

[Как добавить фотографию c обложки mp3 в QPixmap pyqt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344721/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8e-c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8-mp3-%d0%b2-qpixmap-pyqt5/1344740#1344740)

Вам только надо будет получать значение других тэгов
https://exiftool.org/TagNames/ID3.html#v2_3

Answer (score 0):

Решил.

```
    import eyed3
    audio = eyed3.load('D:/книги/audio_book/item_18024/1.mp3')
    print(audio.tag.title)
```